# ResultSet exhausted error is coming while accessing value of cassandra table through scala

Tags: scala, cassandra

I had written a simple code to connect to cassandra and fetch the table value in scala .Here is my code

```
def t()={
 var cluster:Cluster=connect("127.0.0.1")
 println(cluster)
 var session:Session=cluster.connect("podv1");
   // var tx= session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE myfirstcassandradb WITH " +
        //                  "replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':1}")

                          var p=session.execute("select data from section_tbl limit 2;")


 session.close()
 cluster.close
}
```

Although create keyspace thing is working(which i had commented) but when i am trying to fetch the data from table it is giving error like
**ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[data(varchar)]]** .I just started connecting scala to cassandra so may be i am doing some mistake or something.Any help regarding how to get data will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is giving error like ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[data(varchar)]]

This is not an error,  ResultSet is the object returned from execute.  `exhausted` indicates that not all the rows have been consumed by you yet, and `Columns` indicates the name of each column and its type.

So for example in your case of 'p' being the variable assigned to session.execute, you can do something like:

```
var p = session.execute("select data from section_tbl limit 2;")
println(p.all())
```

`all()` the grabs all the rows associated with your query from Cassandra and captures it as a `List[Row]`.   If you have a really large result set (which in your case you don't since you are limiting to two rows), you may want to iterate of the `ResultSet` instead, which will allow the driver to use paging to retrieve chunks of Rows at a time from cassandra.

A `ResultSet` implements `java.util.Iteratable<Row>`, so you can go all the operations you can with iterable.   Refer to the [`ResultSet`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html) api for more operations.

Comment: ok .Great.Can you please tell what actually  session.execute return so that i can use any scala collection to use this.

Comment: session.execute returns a ResultSet.  ResultSet is an iterable (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) of Rows which is just an Object specification that has an Iterator method, you can get a List<Row> from a ResultSet by calling .all() which pages in all the Rows and converts them to a list.